Putting QED symbol lower when using \qedhere in a formula with large subscripts
When ending a proof (from the amsthm package) on a formula that extends quite a bit below the baseline, e.g. when there are stacked subscripts, I find that the \qedhere-command places the box too high up for my personal preference. However, omitting \qedhere places the QED symbol on a new line below the math environment, which is too low.
Is there a way to have the bottom of the QED symbol more or less on the same height as the bottom of the lowest part of the line it is on? In a sense, vertically aligning the symbol to the bottom of its line.
Of course, I could do this on a case-by-case basis with a raisebox or something similar, but I'm looking for a more universal solution, if possible at all.
Image for illustration/clarification.


Welcome to TeX.SE.

I'm not sure if you can using amsthm. You can with ntheorem combined with the empheq. Most often, it is just not worth bothering with even using \qedhere.

I believe that the standard \qedhere is second place after not ending a proof with a formula, but it's personal opinion.
You can raise the formula by its depth.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}% for the colored rule

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Indeed, if $n=2$, then $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-1$ and thus
\[
\raisebox{\depth}{$\displaystyle
  \prod_{\substack{1\le j<k\le n \\ 1\le i\le j\le n}}
  (1-\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k)=
  (1-\lambda_1^2\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_1\lambda_2^2)=
  (1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)=p(-1)
$}
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Indeed, if $n=2$, then $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-1$ and thus
\[
\prod_{\substack{1\le j<k\le n \\ 1\le i\le j\le n}}
  (1-\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k)=
(1-\lambda_1^2\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_1\lambda_2^2)=
(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)=p(-1)
\qedhere
\]
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Indeed, if $n=2$, then $\lambda_1\lambda_2=-1$ and thus
\[
\prod_{\substack{1\le j<k\le n \\ 1\le i\le j\le n}}
  (1-\lambda_i\lambda_j\lambda_k)=
(1-\lambda_1^2\lambda_2)(1-\lambda_1\lambda_2^2)=
(1+\lambda_1)(1+\lambda_2)=p(-1)
\]
and the proof is complete.
\end{proof}

\end{document}

The first instance is how you'd like it.
The second instance is with the QED symbol on the baseline
The third instance is how to do it properly, with some text ending the proof.

